# Is there a way to login with a password to an ssh server using nothing but python sockets?

Tags: python, sockets, ssh, python-sockets

I want to know if there is a way to login to ssh with sockets like so:

```
import socket
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM);
sock.connect(("127.0.0.1",22));
sock.send("username");
sock.send("password");
```

Comment: Unless writing your ssh/ssl library in Python counts, I think the answer is no.

Comment: No, because libraries like [paramiko](http://www.paramiko.org/) (one of the few libraries that allows for something like this) are written at a lower level (some C) - a level that Python a library like `socket` can't necessarily talk to directly

Comment: @ralston IBTD. In theory, you should always be able to do what the OP requested, but of course not with pure sockets. But the encryption and everything should be able to implement in Python. Not that it would be very wise to do so.

Comment: @glglgl there are definitely python crypto libs out there (I'm thinking about cryptography, and pycrypto in particular) that allow for robust python encryption, but if I'm not mistaken, aren't those, again, written at a lower level (some C)? I can't think of a widely used _strictly_ python crypto lib (but definitely point me to one if you know of one). So I'm saying that yes, it's possible to do this from a `.py` file - however, that `.py` file is probably gonna be dependent on py libs written in C, thus not being _pure_ python.

Comment: @ralston I am not sure either that such libraries exist, but it should definitely be possible (in theory) to implement them.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot send username and password directly to the socket.

What goes over the wire is encrypted, and there as well is a certain level of protocol between that.

So you need a layer which provides you with the right protocol on one layer and something which encrypts your communication at a lower level.

Both things can in theory be implemented in Python, but I don't know if such things really exist.

Comment: A categorical "you cannot" isn't really technically correct, though I'm sure there is an overwhelming consensus that "no, it doesn't make sense".

Comment: @tripleee Maybe I phrsed the details wrong, so I edited my answer to become clearer.